# getting error after sending soap request it return statusCode 401 why?

Tags: node.js

1.why getting StatusCode 401 in responce?

2.in request(varbody variable)  sending orderID.

3.in response returns all details corresponds that oderID

4.but that response it gives StatusCode 401

```
     bodyVar="<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ipgapi:IPGApiActionRequest xmlns:ipgapi=\"http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/ipgapi\" xmlns:v1=\"http://ipg-online.com/ipgapi/schemas/a1\"><v1:Action><v1:InquiryOrder><v1:OrderId>0504_0002</v1:OrderId></v1:InquiryOrder></v1:Action></ipgapi:IPGApiActionRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

var options = {
        uri: url,            
        agentOptions: {
            cert: certFileContents,
            key: keyFileContents,
            passphrase: 'abc',

        },
        rejectUnauthorized : false,
        headers:{
             'Content-Type': ' text/xml'
        },
        body: bodyVar       
    };

    request.post(options,function(err,res,body){
    console.log(res.StatusCode);//here im getting 401 why?
   }).auth(Uid,Pass,true)
```

Comment: 401 means invalid authentication credentials. That totally depends on how the server is expecting requests to be authenticated, and if your login credentials are actually valid.

Comment: yes i tested those credentials are valid